# Angular 5: Error during template compile of 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

**Note:**
I did not realize that had posted the wrong code and error for this issue and I have moved this issue to another post at [Angular 5: Function calls are not supported in decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387096/angular-5-function-calls-are-not-supported-in-decorators)

I am so sorry for those of you who took the time to answer. Thank you so much for your responses.

Comment: What version Angular CLI are you using? This could be related to the https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21273 bug

Comment: Could you please try with 1.7.3? Also, would it be possible to provide a minimum working sample of this bug?

Comment: Is the base class `BaseEnvironment` exported?

Comment: 1. is BaseEnviroment imported to this file ? & can you change export variable name eg "export const environment " to "export const environment_something". because this export already exists!

Comment: I am going to close this and create a new a post since I had the wrong code and error to begin with. I am sorry and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're going for

```
import { ProspectBuilderModel } from '../app/models/prospect';
//IMPORT BaseEnvironment CLASS!!!!

export class Environment extends BaseEnvironment {
  production: boolean;
  prospectBuilderModel: ProspectBuilderModel = new ProspectBuilderModel();
}

export const environment: Environment = {
    production: true,
    prospectBuilderModel:{
        buildQuote: true,
        buildAcknowledge: true,
        buildOrganizationInfo: true,
        buildFinancialInfo: true,
        buildTradeInfo: true,
        buildPermissiblePurpose: true,
        buildUserSetup: true,
        buildPackageSelection: true,
        buildPaymentOptions: true,
        buildOrderOptions: true,
        buildVerifyOrganizationInfo: true,
        buildDocusignAuthorization: true,
        buildDocusignContract: true,
        //whatever other properties the BaseEnvironment Class has
    }
}
```

The `BaseEnvironment` class might be what the error is saying isn't exported because you don't have it imported nor is it defined above or below the `Environment` class.  If it were defined you'd have

```
export class BaseEnvironment {...}
```

keyword there is EXPORT.

Also the `const` is read only so doing this

```
export const environment: Environment = new Environment();
```

just sets it as an empty `Environment` meaning you can't do things like

```
this.environment.production = false;
```

In cases where you want something to toggle that won't work because you're suppose to define the values inside the `const` or set its' properties to target other variables that will contain the data/setting you want the const to collect.  If you make a plunkr or stackblitz so we can see what else you have going on there I might be able to help more if this doesn't  resolve it.

Comment: I did not realize (until I read the comments that I was looking at the wrong file since I was trying to run in prod. I have added the correct file's code now and the updated error message I am getting.

Comment: And thank you for the response and possible solution. Can you look at the post again with the code from the correct file and the new error code and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: I am going to close this and create a new a post since I had the wrong code and error to begin with. I am sorry and thank you for the help