# Angular 5: Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I am building a PWA from my Angular app and I am getting the following error when I run `ng build --prod`:

```
ERROR in app\app.module.ts(108,64): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'Environment' was called in 'environment'
'environment' calls 'Environment'.
```

However, it makes no sense because I added `export` to the class as you can see here:

**environment.prod.ts**

```
import { BaseEnvironment } from './base-environment';
import { ProspectBuilderModel } from '../app/models/prospect';

export class Environment extends BaseEnvironment {
  production: boolean = true;
  prospectBuilderModel: ProspectBuilderModel = {
    buildQuote: false,
    buildAcknowledge: false,
    buildOrganizationInfo: false,
    buildFinancialInfo: false,
    buildTradeInfo: false,
    buildPermissiblePurpose: false,
    buildUserSetup: false,
    buildPackageSelection: false,
    buildPaymentOptions: false,
    buildOrderOptions: false,
    buildVerifyOrganizationInfo: false,
    buildDocusignAuthorization: false,
    buildDocusignContract: false
  };
}

export const environment = new Environment();
```

**base-environment.ts**

```
import { ProspectBuilderModel } from '../app/models/prospect';

export abstract class BaseEnvironment {
  abstract production: boolean;
  abstract prospectBuilderModel: ProspectBuilderModel;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
 ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MultiselectDropdownModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxMyDatePickerModule.forRoot(),
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [
...
```

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this error?

Comment: This errror comes from the fact that you tried to call a function into a decorator. If you want help on that, please post the decorator that calls a function, not random code.

Comment: Sorrry, but I do not see where I called a function into a decorator. The code I posted above is what the error was referencing. The `ServiceWorkerModule` line of code in `app.module.ts` is referencing `environment.prod.ts`, which is importing the `BaseEvironment` class. That is why I posted all of that code. I would appreciate any help if you can tell me anything that is missing.

Comment: Okay, then try to build with `ng build --prod --sm=false` please. This should still pop an error, but maybe not the same one.

Comment: It returned the same error bud

Comment: Well then, do you have any repo that we can browse to find your issue ? Because it isn't coming from the code you posted, and you don't seem to be willing to post more code.

Comment: For all I can do now, here is a **[github ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14707)** about the same issue, maybe this can give your more information

Comment: This code is from the company I work for. I could not (obviously) give access to their (or a copy of the) repo. I came across that link that you posted when doing my research, and while I don't doubt this has something to do with AOT compilation, my error and code is different from theirs. I am hoping someone with AOT (in Angular 5) experience can chime in.

Comment: AOT implies a restricted, in several ways incompatible ECMAScript dialect.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DeanFriedland I mean that you can't use all of JavaScript in aot. Furthermore, of the JavaScript that you can use there is a difference in semantics when it comes to decorators that is incompatible. It may or may not bite you but it's best to be aware of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for the solution I finally came up with. Hope this help someone that ever runs into this type of issue. Essentially, I just modified my environment file so that it did not create an instance of the Environment class. I guess Angular no likey the instantiation:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  prospectBuilderModel: {
    buildQuote: false,
    buildAcknowledge: false,
    buildOrganizationInfo: false,
    buildFinancialInfo: false,
    buildTradeInfo: false,
    buildPermissiblePurpose: false,
    buildUserSetup: false,
    buildPackageSelection: false,
    buildPaymentOptions: false,
    buildOrderOptions: false,
    buildVerifyOrganizationInfo: false,
    buildDocusignAuthorization: false,
    buildDocusignContract: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem, here are possible workarounds (if you don't have dynamically loaded properties):

#### 1. As your answer, just object.

But you lose default properties and information about "to implement" properties.

#### 2. Use static classes:

here you lose 'to implement' properties, since abstract statics are [not possible](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600), but you have the types and defaults.

```
// default.env.ts
export class BaseEnvironment {
  public production: boolean = true;
  public specialPropToImpl: boolean = true;
}

// your.env.ts
export class Environment extends BaseEnvironment {
  public specialPropToImpl = true;
}

export const environment = Environment;
```

#### 3. Use default properties object, interface and object assignment:

here you have the 'to implement' properties, types and defaults, but little bit ugly to implement.

```
// default.env.ts
export interface EnvProperties {
  production: boolean;
  specialPropToImpl: boolean;
}

export const defaultEnv = {
  production: true
};

// your.env.ts
export const environment: EnvProperties = {
  ...defaultEnv,
  specialPropToImpl: true
};
```

#### 4. Just one static variable more from environment

simple solution, you keep your subclasses, but every env file must have it. But since new environment files are created by copypaste of old one, this can work.
Depends on production value, you should change the variable value manually.
Not very flexible and maintainable solution. But simple.

```
// your.env.ts
export const enablePwa = true

// app.module.ts
import {environment, enablePwa} from 'env.ts'
//...
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: enablePwa })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your code was working before you added the line 
    *ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })*

Normally when we access the environment variable in app module, it usually refers to the environment files auto-generated by angular cli (which are basically constants and exported as such). I have never tried creating an object of a class and passing it off in app module. This might be causing the problem.

Just try passing a true directly in this line instead of getting it from an object and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the response Arjun but I only want it to be true if `environment.production == true`. If I hardcode the boolean value to true then it will try to register the service worker even if `environment.production == false`  (when I am running in dev evironment). I added this line to `app.module` because the Angular docs say so at:

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Comment: I meant that try replacing it with a hard coded value to pin down the bug. If the AoT build does not fails with this, then we will know for sure that this is the culprit code. 

If this is indeed the issue, you might have to consider some other way of passing this variable.

Comment: Also, the way you are creating the env variables is different how we usually set env variables in an Angular-cli project. 

The env files are created in "src/environments" and more environments can be added in angular-cli.json.
This is the path being expected in the example you have shared above.

Comment: Thank you Arjun. I just got to the office so I am going to give this a shot.

Comment: Hmmmm... It is working with the hardcoded `true`. No error. So what should I do Arjun?

Comment: Use the defualt environment files. At least for the 'production' attribute. 
If you cannot do it in this way, then you will have to dive into how exactly do you get to decide if you are making a prod build ??
When you run "npm build --prod", how are you grabbing the 'prod' part  i.e how do you decide during build time that the build must use enviroment.prod.ts. Maybe use the same logic to pass on the value here .

Comment: Hi Arjun. That is a good question. I am not sure what "npm build --prod" is doing under the covers as far as the "prod" part. Any chance you may be able to point me in the right direction as far as how to find it?